# Matching, retrieve and write the corresponding

Tags: google-sheets, search

I want to search and match the values from Column J with the values in Column A. I'm not sure if the match should be partial, either from the right or left side of the strings. Whenever a value from Column J is found within a value in Column A, I want to retrieve and write the corresponding value from Column J, if there is a match.

I have attached a [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16f0vHuOorJQrtGmo3ln6cINikleGm_m0LkvfxJXpOHQ/edit?usp=sharing) for your reference

your help will be much appreciated

My try:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(J2:J, A2:A)), J2:J, ""), ""))
```

If it is possible, I would like to achieve the desired result using the Left, Mid, and Right functions instead of regular expressions. I have attempted to use these functions, but I am not getting the desired outcome.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEFT(A2:A,SEARCH(" ",A2:A)-1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,let(Λ,tocol(J2:J,1),iferror(+torow(reduce(,sequence(counta(Λ)),lambda(a,c,{a;if(search(index(Λ,c),Σ),index(Λ,c),)})),3)))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LET(names,TOROW(J2:J,1),BYROW(IF(SEARCH(names,A2:A),names,),LAMBDA(_,JOIN(,TOROW(_,3))))))
```

And here's a better one if you are open to use REGEX:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,J2:J))))
```

[image]